# SASS issue with calling mixin

Tags: css, sass

My SASS code:

```
    // rem calculator

    @function calculateRem($size) {
      $remSize: $size / 16px;
      @return #{$remSize}rem;
    }

    @mixin fontsize($size) {
      font-size: $size; //Fallback in px
      font-size: calculateRem($size);
    }

    // variables

    $font-size-regular: fontsize(16px);

    // css

    body {
      font-size: $font-size-regular;
    }
```

This outputs: font-size: fontsize(16px);

Using `@include fontsize(16px);` does work. but I want to put it in a variable if possible

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this

```
// rem calculator

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

@mixin fontsize($size) {
  font-size: $size; //Fallback in px
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}

// variables

$font-size-regular: 16px;

// css

body {
  @include fontsize($font-size-regular);
}
```